# Leading and trailing categories in categorial Chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Say I have a line series with 3 categories on the chart, and the categories represent 3 days, for instance Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday. How can I add an invisible "Monday" category + an invisible "Friday" category to make the line continue to the left/right borders of the chart area?

Comment: Try posting some code that generates a sample chart and maybe a picture of what you would like it to look like...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/evpbwM

Comment: The example you posted is what I am looking for, **but** _Monday_ and _Friday_ should be _hidden_ and the line should stretch from Monday through Tuesday+Wednesday+Thursday until Friday.

Comment: (in my real use case the actual categories are arbitrary dates (the weekdays are just an example), evenly spaced, e.g. hours, monthdays or months; the user can choose)

Comment: What values should the line have on the invisible days? Like this: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/evpbwM

Comment: The view should suggest a line of infinite length (like it is possible in a scatter line plot, but the categorical axis is important to have the option of showing bars in addition to the line). Thus the line **_must_ stretch from chart area border to chart area border** (as stated in my question) and the "hidden" categories (in my example case Monday and Friday) _must_ be  _100% invisible_ (not just hide their labels). They must be invisible, and left (Monday)/right (Friday) of the chart area. In your example, you just removed the category labels.